# C matrix character not appearing printing properly

Tags: c, matrix, char, printf

I am trying to fill a char matrix in C and print it in C but I get only weird characters. I am running this programm on windows, hence the `system(cls);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void paint(char tab[10][10], int lignes, int colonnes)
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < lignes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonnes; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void create(char tab[10][10], int lignes, int colonnes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lignes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonnes; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 || i == lignes--)
                tab[i][j] = 205;
            if (j == 0 || j == colonnes--)
                tab[i][j] = 186;
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 201;
            if (i == 0 && j == colonnes--)
                tab[i][j] = 187;
            if (i == lignes-- && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 200;
            if (i == lignes-- && j == colonnes--)
                tab[i][j] = 188;
            if (i == 50 && j == 50)
                tab[i][j] = 248;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char tab[10][10];
    create(tab, 10, 10);
    paint(tab, 10, 10);
    char i;
    while(scanf(" %c", &i) != 'q')
    {

    }
}
```

I tried changing the output type in printf with `%d` and `%s` as shown in other answers here, but `%d` shows random numbers and `%s` makes the programm crash, I don't know if it is because of a `segfault` somewhere.I also tried using simple characters to fill my matrix, not their ascii value.

Don't mind the ineffective scanf , I am still trying to figure out keyboard input without using enter on my own for now.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, I get the weird characters with `%c`

Comment: What characters did you expect to see, and what characters are you seeing?

Comment: Also, things like `colonnes--` may be the source of your trouble. You want to use `colonnes - 1`, so the original value of `colonnes` is not affected. Same with `lignes`.

Comment: I changed the `colonnes--` to `colonnes-1` but since I compile with the -Werror flag I get a `overflow in implicit constant conversion` error

Comment: That's because `char` on Windows is a signed integral type ranging from -128 to 127. You can use `unsigned char tab[10][10]` in the function declaration for `create` and call it in the `main` function as `create((unsigned char (*)[10])tab, 10, 10);`. Or you can just subtract 256 from the values to create the proper values for `char` on your system and avoid the type cast.

Comment: I actually forgot I had to cast the value in char to make it a character acording to the ascii table, it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there were a few problems with your code, like `colonnes--` changes the value of `colonnes` while cheking your `if` statement

I believe you wanted to draw a rectangle

try this (it's your own code, modified a bit)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char tab[10][10];

void paint(int lignes, int colonnes)
{
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < lignes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonnes; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", tab[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void create(int lignes, int colonnes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < lignes; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < colonnes; j++)
        {
            tab[i][j] = ' ';
            if (i == 0 || i == lignes-1)
                tab[i][j] = 205;
            if (j == 0 || j == colonnes-1)
                tab[i][j] = 186;
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 201;
            if (i == 0 && j == colonnes-1)
                tab[i][j] = 187;
            if (i == lignes-1 && j == 0)
                tab[i][j] = 200;
            if (i == lignes-1 && j == colonnes-1)
                tab[i][j] = 188;
            if (i == 50 && j == 50)
                tab[i][j] = 248;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    create(10, 10);
    paint(10, 10);

}
```

Comment: I changed the `colonnes--` to `colonnes-1` but since I compile with the -Werror flag I get a `overflow in implicit constant conversion` error

Comment: @raiskader did you try the code? because it runs fine on my compiler

Comment: I just made the change I stated above, and I compile with this `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror` flags

Comment: @raiskader you should change `lignes--` to `lignes-1` too

Comment: I did, and I also casted my values in char before putting it in the array, so it works now